# Shows that $M=\{(x,y,z):xy=0, x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\ne +1 \ and -1\} $ is a 1- manifold.

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Shows that $M=\{(x,y,z):xy=0, x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\ne +1  \ and -1\} $ is a 1- manifold.

Attempts: I have tried to let $\Phi(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ and it seems it works for any neighborhood of $(x,y,z)\in M$ but when i try to compute the derivative, then i found that it is of rank 1 so $M$ seems to be a 2 manifolds, but the book ask me to show that it is a 1 manifold and i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: yes but you also have the condition $xy = 0$ so the good function to consider is $\Phi(x,y,z) = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -1, xy) $, and so $M = \Phi^{-1}(\{0,0\}) $

Comment: This is done by eye-balling, not by computation: $M$ consists of four disjoint open half-circles (meridians) !

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the comment by Georges Elencwajg, a computation can be instructive too. In addition to $\Phi$ you should also consider $\Psi(x,y,z)=xy$, the second equation (as  Selim Ghazouani said). Then 
compute
$$\begin{pmatrix} \Phi_x & \Phi_y & \Phi_z \\ \Psi_x & \Psi_y & \Psi_z \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 2x & 2y & 2z \\ y & x & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and show that this matrix has full rank at every point of $M$. More precisely,
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} 2x & 2y  \\ y & x   \end{pmatrix} = 2x^2-2y^2$$
is nowhere zero on $M$.